# Make/have + noun/pronoun + gerund

Tags: verbs, gerunds

Is it correct to say

> 1. I've always had the system unbalanced to the computer
> 2. I've had him happy throughout the year.
> 3. I've always had the system **being** unbalanced to the system.
> 4. I've had her **being** happy throughout the year.

Which one is the correct structure? And what is the official rule for those.

I've seen that the verb as make doesn't need a verb (to be) before adjectives, neither I see gerunds after the noun/prounoun(s)

> 1. She makes me happy.
> 2. He makes the system unbalanced.
> 3. She made me **do** it (it's not **doing**)

I hope someone could explain me the whole rules of these sentences, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gerund v. Participle**

I think you're confusing gerunds and participles. While they look the same (note: in Old English, they were different), they function entirely differently.

The first set of **-ing** words you give are not gerunds, but participles. These are verbal adjectives that modify a noun or pronoun.

Gerunds, however, are verbal nouns. They do not modify other nouns or pronouns.

---

**Make and Have**

For **make**, you use an accusative plus infinitive without "to". All of your examples are correct. It's *she made me **do** it*— no participles needed!

For **have**, the sentences are actually awkward English. It would be better to switch it around:

> 1. The system has always been unbalanced.
> 2. She's been happy this whole year.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer! , so the *have* is an odd structure, but is it grammatical correct?, and is it correct to put present participle in *I've always had the system being unbalanced to the computer*, or it has to be as *Make* which neither needs to add verb *to be* nor present participle, but bare infinitive? Such as *I've had the system unbalanced to the computer*, sorry for taking your time, I am beginner in English I hope you could help with this 

Comment: @123 I agree that none of the *had* sentences by the OP is idiomatic. But your suggestions have no connections between the clause and the speaker, either. (E.g., "I've had him happy throughout the year." links (or tries to link) three things together: *him*, *happy*, and *I* (who've caused that), but "She's been happy this whole year." links only two: *She* and *happy*.)